# lock UIScrollView from right to left scroll

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I want to lock UIScrollView from right to left direction.

I am implementing a registration procedure with 4 views  and i want to load the next view only when the user fill  some informations. So i dont want the user to be able to forward the views manually. The next view will be scrolled with a "next" button inside each view.

But if the user make a mistake i would like to enable the left to right scrolling.

I have use the Page Control Example from apple documentation.

Any suggestions for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might change the `contentSize` of the `UIScrollView` after the field validation for each screen to fit (or not) the next page/s in it.

Comment: The "page control" sample project from Apple set the contentSize to fill all the views from the start and then lazily loads the next view from the current.

Comment: That shouldn't be an issue, it just needs some modification of that code example. Try to load the next view and resize the `contentSize` when the validation is passed and unload the next view and resize the `contentSize` when the validation is not passed.

Comment: I think that i underestand what you said! I have to test it. Thank you